# How can I create a PHP proxy file for handling CORS issue while calling an API?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cors

I want to call an API but I cannot unless I create a proxy PHP file to get around CORS issues. I wrote the below PHP code but for some reason it doesn't work either and now I'm stuck.

Here's the script where I'm calling the API:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#login").click(function () {

        var partnerName = "";
        var partnerPassword = "";
        var partnerUserID = $("#email").val();
        var partnerUserSecret = $("#password").val();

        var apiResponse;
        var token;

        $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.expensify.com/api?command=Authenticate",
            data: {
                partnerName: partnerName,
                partnerPassword: partnerPassword,
                partnerUserID: partnerUserID,
                partnerUserSecret: partnerUserSecret
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                apiResponse = data;
                console.log(apiResponse);
                token = apiResponse.authToken;
                jCode = apiResponse.jsonCode;
                if (jCode == 200) {
                    window.sessionStorage
                    sessionStorage.setItem('authToken', token)
                    window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
                }
                else if (jCode == 401) {
                    alert('Wrong Password! Please enter password again')
                }
                else if (jCode == 404) {
                    alert('Email not found, enter a valid email')
                }
                else if (jCode == 407) {
                    alert('Auth Token expired, please log in again')
                }
                else if (jCode == 402) {
                    alert('Missing Information. Please fill all fields')
                }

            }

        });
    });
});
```

And here's the proxy file:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

$baseURL = $_REQUEST['url'];

function getRequestMethod() {
  return $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; 
}

function getPostData() {
  return http_build_query($_POST);
}


function makeGetRequest($baseURL) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $fullURL = $baseURL; 

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullURL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  
    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    return print_r($json);
    }
}

function makePostRequest($baseURL) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $data = http_build_query($_POST);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    return print_r($json);
    }
}

$response = "";
switch (getRequestMethod()) {
  case 'GET':
    $response = makeGetRequest($baseURL);
    break;
  case 'POST':
    $response = makePostRequest($baseURL);
    break;
  default:
    echo "There has been an error";
    return;
}

echo $response;
```

I know the URL is wrong if I want to access the proxy but can someone can help me with what changes I could do in this code to make it work, that would be really appreciated. Also if there are any resources I could look at to solve this, that would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: `to get around CORS issues` please edit the question to explain/clarify - it seems unlikely creating a proxy is the right way to “fix” that.

Comment: It is likely because server can overcome browser limitations of CORS and access remote URL

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Maybe the line `return print_r($json);` is wrong you should return the `$json` itself

Comment: Does the proxy live at the same host/domain as the JS?

Comment: If it is any help, here’s the [proxy](https://gist.github.com/cjhaas/2102c410eb6abcf1d1473caf12dd4abe) I created a little while back. I was able to get around CORS with this proxy by hosting it on the same domain as the JS.

Comment: @ITgoldman i'm not getting any error per se but when i run the site, the api isnt getting called and site doesn't work

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you for that proxy! what changes do you think I should do in your code to make it work? or if no changes are required, how do i get the proxy up and running? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the required url *param*. try this

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url-of-youe-proxy.php',
    data: {
        partnerName: partnerName,
        partnerPassword: partnerPassword,
        partnerUserID: partnerUserID,
        partnerUserSecret: partnerUserSecret,
        url: "https://www.expensify.com/api?command=Authenticate"
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        apiResponse = data;
        console.log(apiResponse);
        token = apiResponse.authToken;
        jCode = apiResponse.jsonCode;
        if (jCode == 200) {
            window.sessionStorage
            sessionStorage.setItem('authToken', token)
            window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
        }
        else if (jCode == 401) {
            alert('Wrong Password! Please enter password again')
        }
        else if (jCode == 404) {
            alert('Email not found, enter a valid email')
        }
        else if (jCode == 407) {
            alert('Auth Token expired, please log in again')
        }
        else if (jCode == 402) {
            alert('Missing Information. Please fill all fields')
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: ohh, my bad. thanks tho! i'll try this and let you know.